# regex only allow few special character and space in string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write one regex where I need to follow all conditions.

1. characters and numbers are allowed (a-z A-Z 0-9)
2. Space allowed
3. `,-/_()` these only special character allowed.

I have tried like this

```
var str = "The";
  var patt = new RegExp(/^[\w-_.]*$/);
  var res = patt.test(str);
```

it passes in some scenarios but fails in some scenarios

Comment: _“it passes in some scenarios but fails in some scenarios ”_ — please [edit] your question and add examples.

Comment: Just add the special characters to the character set (the ones which aren't already in it, `_` is included in `\w`), and ditch the `new RegExp` while you're at it, you can just use a regex literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
^[\w.)(,/ -]+$
```

- `^` - Start of string
- `[\w.)(,/ -]+` - Matches `alphabets, digits, ( , ) , / , space , - and ,`
- `$` - End of line

```js
let test = (str) => /^[\w.)(,/ -]+$/.test(str)

console.log(test("The vbbv"))
console.log(test("The )( "))
console.log(test("The @"))
```

**side note:-** When using `-` in character class it should be at end of class if you meant to use it as `-` not as range, it's not case here but it's good to follow this rule